# Calling post api with file in the body

Tags: node.js, image, express, post

I want to call a rest API which takes an image as input. But I am not able to pass the file. We can send the URL of the image as an input to the API. Following is the body format.

{ 'url': 'String URL of the Image'}

When I call the same API from the postman it works fine. But not able to understand how can we call it from the nodeJS.

If any one could help me in that.

Thanks & Best Regards,
   Sagar

Answer (score 0):

Use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) package to send your `POST` request here is an exemple :

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('URL_TO_API', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm"  role="form" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

Comment: The solution given is not working. I am calling the custom vision image prediction api of the Microsoft Cognitive services. And I tried several ways but not able to get the result. getting the "BadRequestImageFormat" error message.